# Find words with specific beginning letters in a array of words

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

following situation:
I have a list of words. For example:"Hello","Hey","Help","Shark".

I want to save those in the array apcWord (word-array.. more specific, a pointer-array).
And I have a pointer pcBeg to the beginning string "He"

I have to solve this with this function prototype: 
void search (char *apcString[], char *pcBeg)

How can I filter the array of words and just printf the words which start with "He".

I'am totally confused.. I tried some things with strstr() but no result. The problem is the list of words and filter all words with this "He" beginning. if I just have one word and just want to know if its beginning with "He" or not its no problem.

I hope I made my problem as clear as possible.
Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Could you please add the code you got so far? We call it a [mcve] and it would be helpful to answer your question. Answers without code examples normally get downvotes because they are too broad or not comprehensible.

Comment: Show what you tried, what the input was, what the output should be, and what you got instead. This is far too vague/anecdotal right now. The rule of thumb is that if you have to say "I tried some things", you should show them, with a precise explanation of why they didn't seem to solve your problem, otherwise people can only guess and possibly tell you stuff that you already tried and didn't work.

Comment: `man strncmp`...

Comment: So, I think you simply need to fully understand pointers vs strings vs chars vs ints... CS 50 by Malan is a great video series. Any year probably

Answer (score 0):

*I have a list of words ?* probabaly you want to declare **array of pointer** variable of char type. for e.g

```
char *apcWord[4] = {"Hello","Hey","Help","Shark"};
```

And *I have a pointer pcBeg to the beginning string "He" ?* as you said declare a **char pointer**. for e.g

```
char *pcBeg = "Hi";
```

*I have to solve this with this function prototype: ?* You should learn **how to pass array of pointers to function**. If you are passing array of char pointers to a function, you need to catch with double pointer of char type. Here is the sample code

```
void search (char **apcString, char *pcBeg,int ele) {
   /* logic  */ 
}
```

*How can I filter the array of words and just printf the words which start with "He". ?* use `strncmp()` instead of `strstr()`. open `man 3 strncmp` and third argument of `strncmp()` is useful for your part of question quoting *words which start with "He".* Here is the sample code

```
void search (char **apcString, char *pcBeg,int ele) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int row = 0 ;row < ele ;row++) {
                if(strncmp(apcString[row],pcBeg,strlen(pcBeg)) == 0) {
                                count++;
                }
        }
        printf(" count of %s is : %d \n",pcBeg,count);
}
```

Finally how to call `search()` from `main()` function

```
int main(void) {
        char *apcWord[5] = {"HelloHi","HiHey","Help","Hi","Shark"};
        int ele = sizeof(apcWord)/sizeof(apcWord[0]);
        char *pcBeg = "Hi";
        search(apcWord,pcBeg,ele);/* 3rd arg :- pass the no of element in the array of pointer */
        return 0;
}
```

*I hope I made my problem as clear as possible.  ?* No you didn't. We don't know what code you tried, its advisable to put the code whatever you tried into your question so that you can get more help.

And finally suggest you to read some good C book about array, pointers etc concept & learn how to debug a small code using `gdb` https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .